# OracleCommand Parameter doesn't change the SQL request

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

## **Solved**

It's been a day that I am trying to fix this... 
I want to make an OracleCommande with Parameters, I saw on the web how to do it but my sql request doesn't change.

here my code :

```
string sqlRequest = "SELECT TEXT FROM all_source WHERE TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY' AND name = :Package AND OWNER  = :User ORDER BY line";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlRequest, conn);
cmd.BindByName = true;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add("Package", package.ToUpper());
cmd.Parameters.Add("User", user.ToUpper());
```

where 'package' and 'user' are string.

I don't have any error message but the sql request is the same and the parameters doesn't change.

Thanks in advance, I am sure this is an easy problem...

## **Edit**

You can't call your variable 'user' take another name and it will work !

Comment: well... you haven't *executed* the query, or shown us where `package` or `user` come from, but *in principle*: that looks like it should work...

Comment: TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY'

Comment: package and user are simple string. It SHOULD work... but it doesn't..

Comment: already tried TYPE = 'PACKAGE BODY'

Answer (score 0):

Can you try add new OracleParameter for Add parameters also dont forget execute command.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Package", package.ToUpper()));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("User", user.ToUpper()));
```